# How to import json in wordpress?

Tags: php, json, wordpress, wp-api

I have real estate listing wordpress website. All the listings are stored in custom post type. I was able to fetch listing data through wp-api but I want to post listing through external json file that is provided by other website. 
http://www.century21-montana.co.za/assets/feeds/residential.json .They will update this json regularly.

I don't know it seems stupid question or not. I have no idea how to import this json data regularly by wp rest api. There is very less forum or information of wordpress api modification. Any help from wordpress guruj here would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: Rest API is good way. You can set it by cron or anywhere you think is good. I had work with RestAPI update product on Woocommerce. It's good.

Comment: I know rest api is good way. but where to start or is there any reference for that i can find? I really don't know much anout wp rest api. may be you can help me out ? @QuỳnhNguyễn

Answer (score -1):

If I understand you well, you need to retrieve information from the JSON string and print it browser side. What you need is a javascript code like:

```
for(var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
    var object = json[i];

    console.log(object.id); 
}
```

Of course this assumes that you JSON looks like (just an example):

```
var json = [{
    "id" : "1", 
    "name"   : "hassan"
},
{
    "id" : "2", 
    "msg"   : "asma"}
];
```

Could you provide with a basic structure of the JSON?

Comment: I want to store those json data into wordpress or I can say import into wordpress site. i already gave link of my json. I want to import so that it will automatically display in frontend. hope you got my point.

Comment: `store in wordpress`?. Why to do so and the website is already providing you with the json? if you store in wordpress (I mean your backend) you will need anyway to display using the same way (javacript). About the link you gave, I  think no  one will be  willing to go through that long and complicated structure to help yourself, provide with a simplified example of that json

Comment: The link I gave in question is of other website which will provide this json. and i want to import this into my website. You are right about json file which is bit complex.